# Determinar el numero mas cercano, dentro del array, al numero dado

Tags: java, array

Buenas tengo este problema: a partir de un array y un numero determinar que numero del array es el mas cercano al numero. No me sale

```
 public static int masCercano(int[] numeros, int num)
 { 
    int cercano = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) 
    {
        if (numeros[i] ==  num) 
        {
            return numeros[i];
        }
        else
            if (numeros[i] > num || numeros[i] < num) 
            {
                cercano = numeros[i];
                if (cercano > numeros[i]) 
                {
                    cercano = numeros[i];
                }
                else
                    cercano = numeros[i];
            }
    }
    return cercano;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estás pasando por todos los números preguntando si es menor o mayor al número que necesitamos comparar, es decir simplemente `cercano` lo hará igual al último número que evaluó y fue menor o mayor al número a comparar, pero en ningún momento se está buscando el menor más cercano o el mayor más cercano.

Usando una variable llamada `diferencia` vamos guardando la que hasta el momento sea la menor diferencia entre los números del arreglo y el número a comparar y así mismo vamos guardando cuál es este número de menor diferencia, sea mayor o menor

```
    public static int masCercano(int[] numeros, int num) {
        int cercano = 0;
        int diferencia = Integer.MAX_VALUE; //inicializado valor máximo de variable de tipo int
        for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
            if (numeros[i] == num) {
                return numeros[i];
            } else {
                if(Math.abs(numeros[i]-num)<diferencia){
                    cercano=numeros[i];
                    diferencia = Math.abs(numeros[i]-num);
                }
            }
        }
        return cercano;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Este bloque de código, te permite determinar el número más cercano si no se encuentra una coincidencia exacta, que según entiendo es lo que necesitas.

```
public static int masCercano(int[] numeros, int numero) { 

    int menor = 0;
    int mayor = 0;
    int cercano = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length ; i++) {

        if (numeros[i] == numero) {
            return numeros[i];
        } else if (numeros[i] < numero) {
            menor = numeros[i];
        } else if (numeros[i] > numero) {
            mayor = numeros[i];
        }
    }

    if ((mayor - numero) < (numero - menor)) {
        cercano = mayor;
    } else {
        cercano = menor;
    }

    return cercano;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre, que podrías guardar el indice del valor mas cercano eh ir haciendo restas. Luego el mas cercano al 0 es el que esta mas cerca.

```
public static int masCercano(int[] numeros, int num) { 
  int menorDistanciaActual = Math.abs(num - numeros[0]); // Aca guardas la resta
  int posicionNumeroMasCercano = 0; // Si viene un array con un elemento, es el [0]

  // Empezas en 1, porque ya sabes que el 0 es el mas cercano hasta ahora.
  for (int i = 1; i < numeros.length; i++) {
    int distanciaEntreNumeros = Math.abs(num - numeros[i]);

    if (distanciaEntreNumeros < menorDistanciaActual) {
      menorDistanciaActual = distanciaEntreNumeros;
      posicionNumeroMasCercano = i;
    }
  }

  return numeros[posicionNumeroMasCercano];
}
```

Nota:

- Uso Math.abs() porque queres saber la distancia mínima, y para eso se utiliza el modulo. Si diera un resultado negativo por ejemplo quedando  -100 la distancia seria mayor a la de 5. En cambio con `Math.abs(-100) = 100`
- Si te viene un array con solo un elemento, te retornará ese elemento.

Espero que te sirva. Saludos!