# Como seleccionar el numero mayor más proximo a un numero dado desde un array numerico en PHP?

Tags: php, array

Estimados solicitando nuevamente su sapiencia con temas triviales de PHP si me pueden dar una mano estaré altamente agradecido.
El día de hoy estoy intentando lo siguiente:
Dado un numero objetivo y tomando un arreglo compuesto por 6 números distintos como poder determinar cual de estos seis es el más próximo por la derecha, es decir que sea mayor al numero dado. Por ejemplo: el numero objetivo es 13, el arreglo esta compuesto por los numeros 2,7,8,15, 17 y 189. Por inspección sabemos que el numero más cercano debe ser aquel cuya resta sea positiva y mas proxima al numero 1. Ahora bien, intento plasmar esto en PHP y hasta ahora solo puedo hacerlo con tres numeros. Si me pueden dar sus opiniones y aportes por favor. A continuación el codigo que llevo hasta el momento:

```
        <?php 
    $saldos=array(2,7,8,15,17,189);
    //$saldos=array(2,4,12);
    $falta=13;
    $menor="";
    $mayor="";
    $cercano="";
    $i=0;
    for($i=0;$i<count($saldos); $i++){
        if($saldos[$i]==$falta){
            echo "El valor es identico: " . $saldos[$i];
        }elseif($saldos[$i]<$falta){
            $menor=$saldos[$i];
        }elseif($saldos[$i]>$falta){
            $mayor=$saldos[$i];
        }
    }

    if(($mayor-$falta)<($falta-$menor)){
        $cercano=$mayor;
    }else{
        $cercano=$menor;    
    }

    echo "<br> El numero mas cercano es: " . $cercano . "<br>";
    echo "El arreglo tiene: " . count($saldos) . " posiciones <br>" ;
    var_dump($saldos); 
?>
```

NOTA: Este codigo lo utilice adaptandolo a PHP desde este post: [Determinar el numero mas cercano, dentro del array, al numero dado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/172474/determinar-el-numero-mas-cercano-dentro-del-array-al-numero-dado)

Comment: El array va a estar siempre ordenado o no?

Comment: En efecto estimado Alanfcm, la idea es que desde una consulta de MySQL se tome el arreglo siempre ordenado de menor a mayor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo lo haría de esta manera:

```
//Array desordenado
$data = array(7, 2, 50, 20, 15, 34);
//Número faltante
$falta = 119;

$menor = 0;
$mayor = 0;
$cercano = 0;

//Ordenamos el array de menor a mayor
sort($data);
//Obtenemos el valor menor
$menor = $data[0];

//Obtenemos el valor mayor
$mayor = $data[count($data)-1];

//Ubicamos cual es el valor más cercano desde la derecha al numero faltante

if($falta > $mayor){
    $cercano = $mayor;
}else{
    for($i=0; $i<count($data);$i++){
        if( ($data[$i] - $falta) >= 0 ){
            $cercano = $data[$i];
            break;
        }
    }
}

//Mostramos el resultado
echo "<li>Menor: ".$menor."</li>";
echo "<li>Mayor: ".$mayor."</li>";
echo "<li>Buscado: ".$falta."</li>";
echo "<li>Cercano: ".$cercano."</li>";
```

Comment: Excelente forma de abordarlo estimado Carlos Quintero, mucho mas simple de lo que lo planteaba al inicio. Muchas gracias por tu aporte y pronta respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Estas muy cerca de lo que quieres.  Si el array va a estar siempre ordenado, simplemente tienes que salirte del bucle cuando encuentres un numero mayor que el que buscas.  Algo asi:

```
<?php
    $saldos=array(2,7,8,15,17,189);        
    $falta=13;
    $menor="";
    $mayor="";
    $cercano="";
    $i=0;
    for($i=0;$i<count($saldos); $i++){
        if($saldos[$i]==$falta){
            echo "El valor es identico: " . $saldos[$i];
            break;
        }elseif($saldos[$i]<$falta){
            $menor=$saldos[$i];
        }elseif($saldos[$i]>$falta){
            $mayor=$saldos[$i];
            break;
        }
    }

    if(($mayor-$falta)<($falta-$menor)){
        $cercano=$mayor;
    }else{
        $cercano=$menor;    
    }

    echo "<br> El numero mas cercano es: " . $cercano . "<br>";
    echo "El arreglo tiene: " . count($saldos) . " posiciones <br>" ;
    var_dump($saldos); 

?>
```

Comment: Estimado Alanfcm, gracias por tan oportuno aporte, estaba realmente cerca y no había visto ese detalle, muchas gracias !!

Answer (score 1):

No se que tan eficiente sea este proceso, sobre todo por la parte del "sort" y "array_unique" en arrays enormes, pero si no es muy grande, este método alternativo también puede servir para encontrar el numero mayor más cercano al numero.

```
<?php
$saldos=array(2,7,8,15,17,189);
$falta = 13;

array_push($saldos, $falta); // agrega el numero al array
$newsaldos = array_unique($saldos); // elimina todos los duplicados
sort($newsaldos); // ordena el array ascendentemente
$long = count($newsaldos);

$position = array_search($falta, $newsaldos);
if($long <= 1) { // Si el valor esta solo en el array
    echo 'No hay numeros mayores o menores que ' . $falta . PHP_EOL;
} elseif($position+1 == $long) { // Si el valor quedo de ultimo
    echo 'El numero menor es: ' . $newsaldos[$position - 1] . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'No hay un numero mayor que ' . $falta . PHP_EOL;
} elseif($position == 0) { // Si el valor quedo de primero
    echo 'No hay un numero menor que: ' . $falta . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'El numero mayor es: ' . $newsaldos[$position + 1] . PHP_EOL;
} else { // El valor quedo en medio de otros numeros
    echo 'El numero menor es: ' . $newsaldos[$position - 1] . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'El numero mayor es: ' . $newsaldos[$position + 1] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Salida

```
El numero menor es: 8
El numero mayor es: 15
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte Aeportugal ya lo estoy probando, una pregunta, cuando mencionas arrays enormes, haces referencia a arreglos superiores a cuantos elementos?

Comment: Quizas en el orden de varios cientos de miles o millones de elementos pudiera haber una baja de rendimiento apreciable. Con 50, 200 o 1000 elementos no creo que haya diferencias con otros métodos.

Comment: Basado en el ejemplo que ustedes amablemente me han ayudado a resolver si complicaramos un poco más la situación tal como menciono a continuación que consideran pertinente implementar?. Si todos los numeros del arreglo son menores, podríamos insertar un ciclo para sumar dos o mas componentes de ese array inicial y que sumados sean mayores o iguales que el numero objetivo?. Es decir si el numero objetivo es 119 y el arreglo lo componen los numeros (2,7, 50, 20, 15, 34). Aun no tengo codigo para mostrar pero estoy trabajando en ello, de antemano gracias de nuevo por sus valiosos aportes e ideas.

Comment: @MauroCV08 ya modifique mi respuesta para el caso en que en el array no haya un numero mayor al faltante, la modificación es simple, revisala. Saludos

Comment: Estimado Carlos gracias por tu pronta revisión, no obstante para el caso que te menciono en mi ultimo comentario quisiera realizar una suma de los componentes del arreglo para que sean mayores o iguales al valor del numero objetivo, es decir, numero objetivo=119, como ninguno de los numeros del arreglo es mayor, quisiera que entre ellos se sumaran hasta ser iguales o mayores a numero objetivo (119). Crees que usando variables para cada posición del arreglo podría obtener un resultado aceptable o que me sugeririas en tu opinion?. Agradecido por tu atención, un saludo cordial.